# Correct way to count for a foreign key model in Django template

Tags: python, django

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

let's suppose I need to show in a template how many `Articles` are from a determinate author. This is the view:

```
def myview(request):
    context = {
        'authors': Author.objects.all()
    }
```

simply doing `{{ author.Articles||length }}` would require me to edit the Author model. If this is the correct way (it obviously isn't), should I do this at the `models.py` level or in the view `myview`?

I believe that editing the model in `models.py` would result in a really bad code design.

Doing so in `myview` would require me to do something like this:

```
authors = []
for author in authors:
    count = Article.objects.filter(author__exact=author).count()
    authors.append(author, count)
    horrendously_bad_code_design_context = {
        'authors': authors,
    }
```

What is the correct way to do so? I believe that both these implementations are really bad and 'hacky'.

Comment: You can just do `author.article_set.count()` in your view.

Comment: I didn't know about this "_set" property (I'm still new to Django). If you're sure this works, please post this as an answer for sweet SO points :)

Comment: This is pretty basic, so I am not posting an answer - it would be just reciting documentation. See [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: @Ivan reciting documentation isn't bad, but if you feel bad harvesting easy rep like that you can still make a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a retrieved author and you want to get the article count then using the [related manager's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/) `count` method (`author.article_set.count()`) is probably okay.

On the other hand if you are iterating over an (possibly lagre) `Author` queryset just to get the counts, it will do a lot of queries (one to retrieve all authors and one per author to get the count). This can be easily replaced by an [annotated queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) that will result in only one query:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Author.objects.annotate(article_count=Count('articles'))
```

Later on in your in your template you can just use `{{ author.article_count }}`.